# The type or namespace coud not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net. when I am trying to create an object of the BookDAL class in  `AddBook.aspx` page it doesn't work, and I get the error above, though I have added the reference and and namespace properly, any help please

[image]

This is my code

```
namespace DataAccessLayer.DALS.OLIBDAL
{
   public  class BookDAL
   {
       public int B_Id { get; set; }
       public string IDwithChar { get; set; }
       public int Category_Id { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string ISBN { get; set; }
       public DateTime Published_Date { get; set; }
       public DateTime System_Date { get; set; }
       public string Language { get; set; }
       public string Edition { get; set; }
       public string Author { get; set; }
       public bool Featured { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DataAccessLayer;

public partial class OLIB_AddBook : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    BookDAL book = new BookDAL(); 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not referencing the namespace correctly. As the `BookDAL` is located inside `DataAccessLayer.DALS.OLIBDAL` but you're referencing only `DataAccessLayer`.
So include the following namespace in `OLIB_AddBook.aspx.cs` page:

```
DataAccessLayer.DALS.OLIBDAL
```

**Note**
ASP.Net assumes every folder as a namespace. When you include a parent namespace the classes inside the child namespace(s) will not be accessible until you include them in your working class.

Answer (score 1):

Namespace is:

```
DataAccessLayer.DALS.OLIBDAL
```

Not:

```
DataAccessLayer
```

So replace:

```
using DataAccessLayer;
```

with:

```
using DataAccessLayer.DALS.OLIBDAL;
```